# Macro to find sum of column value in excel if value of column value is yes

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2007

I am making a project in which i have to add a value to sum if it is selected. I have 2 excel sheets one with the values and another with columns containing if it is selected or not.
I have to find the sum of all values which are selected.
I have coded it for one column at a time, but i wanted to use it for all columns eith a trigger  when the value in that column is changed.
The code for a particular column is as follows

```
Dim A, B, As String, Aval, Bval, Ans As Integer
A = Worksheets("Select").Range("A2").Value
B = Worksheets("Select").Range("B2").Value
Aval = Worksheets("Data").Range("A2").Value
Bval = Worksheets("Data").Range("B2").Value

If A = "Yes" Then
    Aval = Aval
Else:
    Aval = 0
End If

If B = "Yes" Then
    Bval = Bval
Else:
    Bval = 0
End If

Ans = Aval + Bval 

Worksheets("Select").Range("D2").Value = Ans
```

The excel sheets are of the sort
Data
A   B
10  20

Select
A    B   Ans
yes  no  10
yes  yes 30

Comment: does the built-in function SUMIF do what you are looking for?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I get your question completely. Do you mean you want to do this "Yes"-check for the whole column? In that case I would loop through the rows in the column, i.e.

```
For i = 1 to lastrow 
    If cells(i,1) = "Yes" Then
        Do something
    End If
Next i
```

Does that help?

Also, I believe it would be possible to do this with a simple if-formula, i.e. you check if Select.A1=Yes, then Data.A1 will be something. In another cell you can then take the sum of the column/row.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

a) I am not sure the variable declaration works. Please check that out. I always prefer to declare each type separately. 
b) Remove the colon ":" after Else